# How to reload page with javascript without sending POST information again

Tags: javascript, post

I have a page, to which I POST information via `form method="post"`. I would like to relaod it with JavaScript, but `location.reload(true)` and `location.reload()` makes browsers ask if I want to send the POST data again.

I would like to make JavaScript reload the page with GET instead of POST to skip the POST data.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
window.location.href = window.location.href
```

try

Comment: Just how easy that was. Had that feeling. Thank you a bunch!

Comment: When I do this, the page doesn't reload at all because the URL doesn't change

Comment: It should. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Confirmed, if I enter this into a Chrome's console, nothing happens (2020)

Comment: In my Firefox 124.0.1 this shows the confirmation dialog to repost.

Answer (score 1):

To reload a page without post data using javascript the easiest way I've found is to use an extra form to submit - this works regardless of whether the url is # or anything.

```
<form name="reloadForm">
    <button type="submit">
        Continue
    </button>
</form>
<script>
    document.reloadForm.submit() ;
</script>
```

That will show a button briefly on screen that the user can click continue on but the script will automatically submit it  - this method sorts out a number of problems - the form is empty so it will not submit any post data (the button isn't named so even that won't submit a value).  It works even if the url is set to #, and finally it gives a backup in case the user has disabled javascript (or the javascript doesn't work for some reason) they've still got a continue button available to click.

Comment: I've managed to reduce this idea to this javascript: `document.body.innerHTML += '<form name="reloadPage"><input type="hidden" name="_" value="_"></form>'; document.reloadPage.submit();`

Comment: Although I later found out, that it can be unreliable for some reason, probably some user control action - but if I add the form to html first and user makes a click action to which I bind, then the form submission seems to always work.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted response is what I knew too, seems like it has become problematic, jave.web said in 2020 that it did nothing in chrome, currently my firefox pops up the repost dialog. So here's a surefire way to do it, although not the most elegant, it's inspired by jquery's nocache:

```
location.href = location.href + (location.href.includes('?') ? '&' : '?') + '_=' + Date.now();
```