# How to reload a page with javascript sending both GET and POST, and append additional parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with an select box, which fires an onChange event. In this Java-Script snippet, I would like to reload the current page, including the GET and POST parameters that where sent during request. AFAIK, this can be achieved by using `window.location.reload()`, or `window.location.href = window.location.href` when sending [POST data is not required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25612184/how-to-reload-page-with-javascript-without-sending-post-information-again).

However, I need to append an additional value (actually, the value of the select element), additionally to the previously sent element. I do not care whether the data is sent using POST or GET. Is there a way to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: Do you have a way or place that you are storing data from a previous post? If you don't have the server stashing it somewhere the only way to duplicate the previous post request would be to reload, in which case you couldn't append further data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you are going to have to rebuild a request from scratch. In the case of get requests, the arguments are easily accessible in the query string but post requests are a little trickier. You will need to stash all that data in hidden input elements or something so that you can access it.

Then you can try something like this:

```js
var queryString = windlow.location.search; //args from a previous get
var postArgs = $("#myPostArgsForm").serialize(); //args from a previous post... these need to be saved and added to the html by the server

//your additional data... this part you probably need to adapt
//to fit your specific needs. this is an example
var myNewArgName = encodeURIComponent("newArg");
var myNewArgVal = encodeURIComponent("Hello!");
var myNewArgString = myNewArgName + "=" + myNewArgVal;

//if there is no queryString, begin with ?
if(!queryString) {
  queryString = "?"
}
//if there is, then we need an & before the next args
else {
  myNewArgString = "&" + myNewArgString;
}

//add your new data
queryString += myNewArgString;

//add anything from a previous post
if(postArgs) {
  queryString += "&" + postArgs;
}

window.location.href = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + querystring
```

```html
<form id="myPostArgsForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="prevQuery" value="whats up?" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive code. My framework stores the POST data of the previous post, hence I can use them to build the new request. Solution works, and I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple really; have onChange fire a function that uses getElementById to figure out the selector value and then just use window.location to send the browser to the literal: http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.html?selectval=123

then, in the body onload() method, fire another JS function that checks the "get var" like:

```
function (GetSelector) {
   var TheSelectorWas = getUrlVars()["selectval"];
   alert(TheSelectorWas);
}
```

and do whatever you need to do in that function (document.writes, etc). BTW, posting the actual code you're using is always a good idea.

-Arne